# Getting data from Firebase Database from multiple paths

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem with getting data from Firebas eDatabase from multiple paths. I am writing an Endomondo clone and I have a database structure as follows:

```
users:
    user_1:
        name:
        ....
        friends:
            user_2
            user_3
    user_2:
        ...
workouts:
    user_1:
        workout_1:
            distance:
            duration:
            path:
            etc.
    user_2:
```

Now I want to list all workouts of my friends in feed tab. So to do it I need to do three things.

1) Iterate over my profile (user_1) to get all my friends ids.

2) When I have those ids, I need to iterate over their profiles to get their names to display.

3) Iterate over workouts to get all workouts  of my friends.
And now I want to put all this information in one object, lets say "FriendWorkout" which would look like:

```
FriendWorkout:
    String friendName;
    Workout workout; // contains all workout data(path, time, distance)
```

And put all of those object in the list so I can pass it to the adapter.

JSON:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "BLhXU5eJGtZayRrUGYTrGiImg313" : {
      "avatarUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/alphaui-40ee2.appspot.com/o/avatars%2Favatars%2FBLhXU5eJGtZayRrUGYTrGiImg313.jpg?alt=media&token=c6b00937-6970-4f43-8ea4-b9add33c43e1",
      "email" : "xhh@gmail.com",
      "firstName" : "Jadwiga",
      "friends" : {
        "CTS134a7vtMWcBs7N2ynDKSyKj23" : true,
        "DoXUtoa7vtMWcBs7N2ynDKSyKj23" : true
      },
      "lastWorkout" : "-LRGN8H6a1esdUPvb-ve",
      "surname" : "Szalony"
    },
    "CTS134a7vtMWcBs7N2ynDKSyKj23" : {
      "avatarUrl" : "none",
      "email" : "ofca@wp.pl",
      "firstName" : "Leokadia",
      "friends" : {
        "BLhXU5eJGtZayRrUGYTrGiImg313" : true
      },
      "lastWorkout" : "dasdsa",
      "surname" : "Fin"
    }
  },
  "workouts" : {
    "BLhXU5eJGtZayRrUGYTrGiImg313" : {
      "-LRGN3sEJgrNxRH3Hf6j" : {
        "date" : "Wed, 14 Nov 2018 09:39:41",
        "distance" : 0,
        "duration" : "0:00",
        "workoutName" : "Running"
      },
      "-LRGN68Z_s5dUjlkuhB-" : {
        "date" : "Wed, 14 Nov 2018 09:39:50",
        "distance" : 0,
        "duration" : "0:00",
        "workoutName" : "Running"
      }
    },
    "DoXUtoa7vtMWcBs7N2ynDKSyKj23" : {
      "-LRGSafxbmKWGLy5x-Kd" : {
        "date" : "Wed, 14 Nov 2018 10:03:50",
        "distance" : 0,
        "duration" : "0:02",
        "workoutName" : "Running"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It might be very easy. Please show us your real database structure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo updated post with JSON.

Comment: Ok, I'll write you an answer right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need can be solved by querying the database three times, once to get the `friendUid`, second to get the corresponding `names` and third  to get the `Workout` objects of the corresponding friends. So please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference friendsRef = rootRef.child("users").child(uid).child("friends");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String friendUid = ds.getKey();

            DatabaseReference friendUidRef = rootRef.child("users").child(friendUid);
            ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String firstName = ds.child("firstName").getValue(String.class);
                        String surname = ds.child("surname").getValue(String.class);
                        String friendName = firstName + " " + surname;
                        Log.d(TAG, friendName);

                        DatabaseReference friendUidWorkoutsRef = rootRef.child("workouts").child(friendUid);
                        ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                List<FriendWorkout > workouts = new ArrayList<>(); //List added
                                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    Workout workout = ds.getValue(Workout.class);
                                    Log.d(TAG, workout.getWorkoutName());

                                    //Create an object of FriendWorkout as needed
                                    FriendWorkout friendWorkout = new FriendWorkout(friendName, workout);
                                    workouts.add(friendWorkout); //Add object to the list
                                }
                                ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
                                ArrayAdapter<Data> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
                                listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); //Set the adapter
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
                            }
                        };
                        friendUidWorkoutsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
                }
            };
            friendUidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
friendsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have another question. So let's say I want to add all those new FriendWorkout objects in the list  `List<FriendWorkout > workouts = new ArrayList<>();` and then notify the adapter that he has new data to load. How to do it in the nice way to avoid unnecessary calls on the adapter?

Comment: In general, other questions that derive from the initial question, should be considered new questions and should pe added here on stackoverflow separately. Seeing that you are a new contribuitor, I just have updated my answer with your new request. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Your answers helped me very much. Thank you. I will keep all your tips/comments in my mind for the future! Thank you, Mr. Alex.